# I want to sort columns in excel by the name before a specific character

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a question regarding Microsoft Excel.

I have a very large data .csv file. I want to sort this file horizontally, but there is can't seem to find how. Now my data looks like this:

I need to do the following:

For every value before the ‘:’ in the cell, there must be made a column where all the data with the same value before the ':' is placed in.

Please help me, and send me in the right direction.

Kind regards,

Comment: your input image is badly not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Few Excel Formulas, we can separate the VALUE after and before " : "

Let's Suppose we have our Value at ***Cell "A1"***

**Get Value BEFORE " : "**

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1,1)-1)
```

[Here is the Screen Short for Getting Before ":" Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFZUP.png)

**Get Value After " : "**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1,1))
```

[Here us the Screen Short for Getting After ":" Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ippk.png)

**NOTE :** You can use can Character instead of " : "like " $ " " , " " _ "

> I have seen your File you need to Insert a column before the value
>   column and Insert the formula and drag it to the end.